# Instagram API pagination going to previous 20 photos

Tags: reactjs, coffeescript, instagram-api

I have all of a user's media content (let's say, 200 photos) displayed in a table. Instagram only allows a max of 20 photos, so I'm using their pagination feature with maxId and minId.

I'm on page 1, and it displays 20 photos. Great.

```
Page 1
photo #0
photo #1
...
photo #19 with maxId: 123
```

To get to page 2 (the next 20 photos), I need the maxId of page 1's last photo. Great.

```
Page 2
photo #20
photo #21
...
photo #39 with maxId: 456
```

The same applies getting to page 3 - all I need is the maxId of page 2's last photo. However, when I'm on page 3 and I want to view the previous 20 photos on page 2, I actually go all the way back to page 1's photos because Instagram thinks that I'm trying to view the previous 40 photos, but they can only display the first 20.

```
Page 3
photo #40
photo #41
...
photo #59 with maxId: 789
```

I'm keeping track of the current page's minId through a stack and popping it as we navigate backwards so that the correct minId is being passed through. I'm not getting the right photos though, and I'm just a bit confused on Instagram API's documentation of minId and maxId:

> MIN_ID    Return media later than this min_id.
>
> MAX_ID    Return media earlier than this max_id.

So to go back from page 3 --> page 2, do I need the id of page 3's first photo set as maxId and id of page 2's last photo as minId? Or is it the other way around?

Answer (score 1):

I would just save the API URLs for each page.

page1 is simple, you just need API URL without any `max_id` or `min_id`
page2 will be API URL with `max_id` of last media id from page1 response
page3 will be API URL with `max_id` of last media id from page2 response

At each of these calls, save the API URLs for corresponding pages, when going back to a page, just use the API URL saved for that page and load reponse